# angular form is never reset

Tags: angular, forms

I am using angular 9 and formController.

Depending on a button click, the provided form add or remove a field, so I would like that, when the button is clicked, the form (AND error) all to be reseted.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mku86s

I tried all of this

```
/*  Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((field) => {
      console.log(field)
      this.form.get(field).setErrors(null)
    }) */
    this.formDirective.resetForm()
    this.form.reset()
/*  this.form.updateValueAndValidity()
    this.formDirective.resetForm()
    this.form.reset()
    this.form.markAsPristine()
    this.form.markAsUntouched()
    this.form.clearValidators() */
```

but nothing works...

why ?

Comment: I think you'll need to add a new variable like `showError` for your `ngIf` statements, because the errors are always present in the formControl, even before the users touches the form.

Comment: shouldn't reset hide them all ? or `clearValidators`

Answer (score 0):

It is not happened because the real input element in `app-input` component or `app-input` component itself is not linked with any form control. You reactive form should be smth like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name"/>
  <input formControlName="email"/>
  <input formControlName="userRole"/>
  <!-- etc -->
</form>
```

---

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I tried to pass `formControlName` to the app-input component, but it doesn't work. Does it have to be a direct nested child element and not in another component ?

Comment: @Bobby it have to be linked directly to input element in your case or `app-input` should be [*custom control*](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html)